# Why when restoring an archive object from glacier in storage gateway it does not appear the error that AWS shows in their blog?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, aws-storage-gateway

We are following this blog [1] to automate the restoration of archived objects through aws storage gateway. But as we commented in the blog post, we do not find the log with the `type: InaccessibleStorageClass`. But with the `type: FileSystemAudit`. Why it does not appear this error type logs?

```
{
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "bucket": "mybucket",
    "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:role/sts-test",
    "source": "share-E1B9B18A",
    "type": "InaccessibleStorageClass",
    "operation": "S3UploadFailure",
    "key": "myfile.txt",
    "gateway": "sgw-B8D938D1",
    "timestamp": "1565740862516"
}
```

```
{
 "sourceAddress": xxxxxxxxx, 
"clientUid": xxxxxxxxx, 
"source": xxxxxxxxx, 
"type": "FileSystemAudit", 
"version": "1.0", 
"objectType": "File", 
"bucket": xxxxxxxxx, 
"clientGid": xxxxxxxxx,
"objectName": "/test-windows/lambda.png", 
"shareName": xxxxxxxxx, 
"operation": "ReadData", 
"gateway": xxxxxxxxx,
"timestamp": "1657016695584", 
"status": "Failure" 
}
```

[1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/automate-restore-of-archived-objects-through-aws-storage-gateway/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this type was not found because we were choosing the log group of the file share not the log group of the storage gateway. The storage gateway log group was the one with this specific type. Thank you anyway :)